# MacOS Calendar Notifications Keep Coming Back - Can This be Fixed?

Tags: macos, notifications, calendar, android, google-calendar

I'm looking for a way to dismiss not just an x-minutes-in-advance notification for a given event, but all future notifications as well, without simply deleting the calendar event.

I'd settle for a way to individually turn off notifications at the time of the event. (I.e. event x generates a notification 10 minutes before, but NOT at the time of the event. That doesn't work - there's no "at time of event" notification in the MAC Calendar UI, so I can't delete it, but Calendar gives me such a notification anyway.)

I don't think either one is possible, but if anyone knows how to do this, they are probably here on AskDifferent.

Here's a typical scenario:

- I have a task I'd like to do around 9 AM
- I get a reminder at 8:50 AM, or maybe earlier.
- I do the task at 8:51 - or maybe already did it at 8:30 AM
- I dismiss the notification, and it comes back at 9 AM.

I want a way to tell MacOS that I'm never going to want another reminder for this event.

It's possible - but inconvenient - to delete the "event" at the same time as its first notification. You have to jump from notification to calendar app, then right click to delete the "event". But that leaves no history.

Obviously the Apple-designed way to do this would be to use Reminders, but I need access to these reminders on my Android phone, and AFAIK Apple's Reminders program isn't Google-compatible.

Also, if anyone knows how to get Apple's Reminders App to play nicely with Android, preferably via Google calendar, that would also solve my problem.

MacOS Monterey 12.5.1;
Android 12

Comment: did you try to use the Repeat, and END  it

Comment: It's just one event, not a repeating event. The problem is that MacOS will always give me a new notification at the time of the event. I can't tell it "shut up about this" without deleting the calendar entry.